# How to create a 3D density map of a system of varying number of particles?

Tags: imaging, imagej

I have a time-dependent system of varying number of particles (~100k particles). In fact, each particle represents an interaction in a 3D space with a particular strength. Thus, each particle has (X,Y,Z;w) which is the coordinate plus a weight factor between 0 and 1, showing the strength of interaction in that coordinate. Here http://pho.to/9Ztti I have uploaded 10 real-time snapshots of the system, with particles are represented as reddish small dots; the redder the dot, the stronger the interaction is.

The question is: how one can produce a 3D (spatial) density map of these particles, preferably in Matlab or Origin Pro 9 or ImageJ? Is there a way to, say, take the average of these images based on the red-color intensity in ImageJ?

Since I have the numerical data for particles (X,Y,Z;w) I can analyze those data in other software as well. So, you are welcome to suggest any other analytical approach/software

Any ideas/comments are welcome!

Comment: well, have you tried anything so far?

Comment: yep; ImajeJ and Origin Pro; both not successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R packages [`misc3d`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/misc3d/misc3d.pdf) and [`rgl`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgl/rgl.pdf). The function `image3d` in `misc3d` does what you need and is very parametrizable via `rgl` (change the transparency, the view angle, axes, etc...). I used it with fairly big arrays (~10000000 data points/plots) and it produced great 3D density plots.

Both R (e.g. package `biOps`) and Matlab (image processing toolbox) have very powerful tools for image analysis if you need to get for example RBG levels in your plots but as far as I understood, you have the 3D arrays containing the interaction values, right?

Matlab proposes similar tools if you prefer Matlab (don't remember the exact functions) over R and both will require a fair amount of RAM as the data must be loaded in the environment.

As your system is time dependent you can also create movies fairly easily if you wish so (e.g. rgl's `movie3d` function).

Here a quick example of a 3D density plot:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yep; you're right. I have the arrays of $x$ , $y$ , and $z$, and $w$ for the interactions locations and strength.

Comment: Ok, then it is quite straightforward to make such plots using those functions.

Comment: Well, I installed R , `misc3d` and `rgl` packages. But, to use `image3d`, one needs a "3 dimensional data array". My collection of $(X,Y,Z)$s makes a 2D array.  Should I convert it to 3D??? and how??

Comment: @deeep how is a collection of (X,Y,Z) 2D?

Comment: Well, here is the collection of my $(X,Y,Z)$s:  

$$x_{1@t1} \quad y_{1@t1} \quad z_{1@t1}$$

$$x_{2@t1} \quad y_{2@t1} \quad z_{2@t1}$$

$$...$$

$$x_{N@t1} \quad y_{N@t1} \quad z_{N@t1}$$

$$--------------$$

$$x_{1@t2} \quad y_{1@t2} \quad z_{1@t2}$$

$$x_{2@t2} \quad y_{2@t2} \quad z_{2@t2}$$

$$...$$

$$x_{M@t2} \quad y_{M@t2} \quad z_{M@t2}$$

$$--------------$$

$$.$$
$$.$$

Where $t1$ refers to time 1, $t2$ time 2, etc. Also $N$ is the number of particles (=interactions) at time 1, $M$ number of particles at time 2, and so on.
To me this is a 2D array, like in Matlab.

Comment: @deeep I see. To convert that to a 3D matrix you can use your X,Y,Z coordinates to map the w into a 3D matrix. For example a 3D matrix M@t1 (casted using `array()` and of the size of your entire space) will contain the value $M(X_1,Y_1,Z_1)=w_1$, $M(X_2,Y_2,Z_2)=w_2$ ... $M(X_N,Y_N,Z_N)=w_N$ and I guess 0 for all values not mapped by any particles. I guess the assignment `M(C)=w` would work with C being your coordinate matrix @t1. Once this done, you can call the function image3d(M,x,y,z) with x,y,z being the vectors $x=\{x_1,...,x_N\}$ and so on. You will need to create $t$ 3D matrices.

Comment: @deeep if you need more help we might chat instead of using the comment section. See https://chat.stackoverflow.com/. You will need 20 reputation points though. Also you might want to shoot me an email with say the data @ t1 so I can make a R script that would do that and so you have an actual example using your data.

Comment: Thank you! Like you said chat is not an option for me at this point. I dont have enough reputation. I'll send you the data.

Comment: @deeep ok see me my profile.

Comment: Cagliari2005, I was able to create a 2D array (=matrix) $N$ x $3$ of N tuples (x,y,z) with the following piece of code (I'm pretty sure there must be a much neater and cleverer way to do so, but I am not familiar enough w/ R). Yet, was not able to convert it to a 3D array using weight factors $w$ .


`df <- read.table("xyzw.dat")

x <- array(df$V1)

y <- array(df$V2)
z <- array(df$V3)
w <- array(df$V4)
ar2d <- array(0,dim=c(N,3))
for (i in 1:N)
{
  ar2d[i,1] <- x[i]
  ar2d[i,2] <- y[i]
  ar2d[i,3] <- z[i]
}`

I sent you an email yesterday w/ the data @ times 1 to 10.

Comment: deleted my previous comment as I thought I found a direct solution but no. You will need to estimate a weighted kernel. I am not certain as how to exactly incorporate the  weight. pythonist answer is more complete than mine.

Comment: So, suppose that they are all equally weighted, i.e. there is no weight function. Then how should I make a 3D array from $(X,Y,Z)$s?

Answer (score 1):

One approach: fit a [kernel density estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) to the observed coordinates $\{ (X_i,Y_i,Z_i) \}$ and color by density: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25286811/how-to-plot-a-3d-density-map-in-python-with-matplotlib/25354417#25354417

Incorporating the weights $w$ of each observation is a bit trickier, but there's code to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27623919/weighted-gaussian-kernel-density-estimation-in-python/27623920#27623920 , which you can swap in instead of `stats.gaussian_kde`.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to analyze that much data in ImageJ seems likely to end in frustration. Matlab is probably a more productive angle. Personally, I would use Python. Specifically, the numpy module. Try looking into the [histogramdd](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html) function in numpy. It might be able to accomplish what you're after.